# How to make width of <li> flexible?

Tags: css, list, menu, unordered

I'm having a problem with my menu, in which there's search form. And when the input is on focus the elements of the menu have to be with less width, but I don't know how to make it work...

```
    <nav role="navigation" class="holder">
    <ul id="navigation">
        <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li><a href="#">Random Page</a><li>
        <li id="search">
            <form method="get" action="">
                <input type="text" name="string">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Go">
                <div class="c_l"></div>
            </form>
        <li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the code, in which you can see what exactly I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/YcLtw/

Comment: what is the problem? what do you expect it to do?

Comment: I want to make the width of the menu links smaller when the input of  the search form is on focus, so that the whole form can stay in the menu. (sorry if I can't describe what I'm trying to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean that your search box shift down when it doesn't have enough width to expand, then you can fix this by doing the following:

```
#navigation {
   position: relative;
}
#search {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YcLtw/1/)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you!!! Originaly I was trying to change the width of the hyperlinks so that the expanded search box can fit, but I guess that would work too :)

Answer (score 0):

You want the search input to have less width,but you write this in your css:

```
#navigation > #search input[type=text]:focus{width:150px;}
```

If you still want the width to increase when the input is focused, set the width smaller.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YcLtw/2/)

I add a border for the input.By the way,`border:0;`should be corrected as `border:none;`

Comment: No, I want the hyperlinks to have less width when the search input is on focus, so that the whole form can stay on its place. :)